# Обновление поля time_shipping и выборка списка курьеров

Tags: access, база-данных, mysql, запрос, sql

Есть таблицы:

1. **region:** *id_country, id_town, remote*

   - таблица с городом, областью и отдаленностью от пункта продажи
2. **transport:** *id_transp, name_transp, speed_transp*

   - таблица с названием и скоростью транспорта доставки
3. **supported:** *id_region, id_transport, time_shipping*

   - таблица для связки одного региона и нескольких типов транспорта, а `time_shipping` предполагаемое время доставки = `region.remote/transport.speed`
4. **courier:** *id_courier, id_region*

   - связка, опять же, одного курьера с несколькими региона

Задача: обновлять поле `time_shipping` автоматически в новой добавленной записи значением `region.remote/transport.speed` (индексы у `time_shipping.id_region` c `region.id_region` и `time_shipping.id_transport` c `transport.id_transport`, конечно, совпадают). И вторая задача - выборка на список курьеров, которые работают в данном регионе, возможные транспорты и периоды доставки.

---

Совсем запутался, помогите. Нужны только запросы, без реализации на каком-либо языке программы.

Comment: Ка-ка-как в этом можно разобраться? Советую задавать по 1 вопросу и задавать вопрос более кратко.

Comment: поле time_shipping ненадо создавать как и писал @Yura Ivanov . более того речь идет о acess посему вы можете создать запрос (имеется в виду не написать а написать и сохранить ) который будет возвращать это значение ( а значит и триггеров не надо ). кстати вы забыли добавить метку учебное задание

Answer (score 1):

1)

В таблице 3 надо убрать `time_shipping`, если оно всегда вычисляемое, создать `VIEW`, в котором будет вычисляться это значение. Если оно может изменяться, нужно создать  `trigger` на вставку, где устанавливать это значение. синтаксис для разных субд разный, обратитесь к справке.

2)

```
SELECT c.id_courier, t.id_transp, s.time_shipping
FROM courier as c
LEFT JOIN supported as s on c.id_region = s.id_region
LEFT JOIN trasnport as t on s.id_transport = t.id_transp
WHERE c.id_region = :id_region
ORDER BY c.id_courier, s.time_shipping ASC, t.id_transp
```

Запрос вернет список всех курьеров в регионе, способных доставить соответствующим транспортом за время, фактически это будет умножение всех курьеров в регионе и всех видов транспорта в регионе. Т.е. можно решить двумя запросами, время доставки получается тут не зависит от курьера...